# Diffeomorphism between the torus $T^2$ and $f^{-1}(0)$

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to solve the following questions.

> Let $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2-4)^2+z^2-1$.
>
> - a) Show that $0$ is a regular value of $f$ and that $f^{-1}(0)$ diffeomorphic to $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ $\qquad$
> - b) Define an explicit embedding $g:T^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ and find its parametrizations. $\quad$

**My attempt**:

**a)** $D_f(x,y,z)=(4x^3-12xy^2,4y^3-12x^2y,2z)$ and so for every point $p\neq 0$, we get that $D_f(x,y,z)$ is of full rank and in particular also for the set of all points such that $f(p)=0 $. Hence, by definition, $0$ is a regular value of $f$. Moreover, $f^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth manifold of dimension 3-1=2. Now I want to find a diffeomorphism between $f^{-1}(0)$ and $T^2$ using that $f^{-1}(0)$ is similiar to the torus cartesian parametrization $(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2+z^2=r^2$. Unfortunately I didn't find out how to connect between them. Any suggestions? $\quad$

**b)** Define $g:R^3\rightarrow R$ such that $g(x,y,z)=(R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2+z^2=r^2$. It is obvious that $g^{-1}(0)=T^2$ is a smooth manifold of dimension 2. Is this proof sufficient to show that $g$ is an embedding? If so, can I use the torus paramatrization as the embedding parametrizations?

Comment: The TeX code for $\Bbb R$ is `\mathbb R`, or just, `\Bbb R`. If you use that, then you won't have to use $R$ to mean two different things in **b)**.

Comment: b) requests that $g : \Bbb T^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ be an *explicit* embedding. The $g$ you defined is neither $\Bbb T^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ nor an explicit embedding.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are right, I didn't noticed it. Do you have any suggestions regarding my questions?

Comment: Yes. First learn what parametrization means. (What you called a parametrization is not one - it is simply the equation of a torus. $y=x^2$ is the equation of a parabola. $\psi : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2 : t \mapsto (t, t^2)$ is a parametrization of that parabola.) Second, consider [what this surface looks like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2-4)%5E2+%2B+z%5E2+%3D+1). How would you map the points of $\Bbb T^2 = S^{1}\times S^{1} = \{(e^{i\theta}, e^{i\phi}) : \theta, \phi \in [0, 2\pi)\}$ to this surface?

Comment: @PaulSinclair How can we tell which $(e^{i\theta},e^{i\phi})$ corresponds to $(e^{i\theta},e^{i\phi},\pm\sqrt{1-(e^{2i\theta}+e^{2i\phi})^2-4})$?

Comment: I think I managed to solve (b): let us define $\chi:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ such that $\chi(e^{i\theta},e^{i\phi})=((R+rcos\theta)cos\phi,(R+rcos\theta)sin\phi,rsin\theta)$. $\chi$ is injective since $\theta,\phi\in [0,2\pi)$. Moreover, $rank(d\chi)=2$. Therefore, $nullity(d\chi)=0$ and hence $d\chi$ is injective. Overall, by definition, we get that $\chi$ is an embedding. The parametrization of $\chi$ is just its inverse $\chi^{-1}$.

Comment: I accidentally wrote $\chi$. I meant $g$

Comment: For a), that is not how you want to map the torus to that surface. Treat $\theta$ as the angular location around the axis of revolution of a vertical half-plane. That half-plane intersects the surface in a simple closed smooth curve. Any simple closed smooth curve is diffeomorphic to a circle, in particular to the circle of $\phi$.

Comment: For b). that works, except you still haven't got "parametrization" figured out. The parametrization is just the map $$[0,2\pi)\times [0,2\pi) \to \Bbb R^3 : (\theta, \phi) \mapsto ((R+r\cos\theta)\cos\phi,(R+r\cos\theta)\sin\phi,r\sin\theta)$$ (Use `\cos` and `\sin` instead of just `cos` and `sin` to make mathjax handle them right, The same works for all the elementary functions.)